# 1 - 100 prime or not in Java

Tags: java

This is a basic prime number checker. How would I loop this code so it tells me every single number from 1 to 100 and if its prime or not. For example:

1 is not a prime number

2 is a prime number

3 is a prime number

and so on until 100. This is not a user generated program just straight up if I run it it gives me all 100 numbers

```
    int check;
    int number;
    boolean prime = true;
    for (int i=2; i<=check/2; i++)
    {
        number = check%i;
        if (number == 0)
        {
            prime = false;
        }
    }
    if (prime == true)
    {
        System.out.println(check + " is a prime number");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(check + " is not a prime number");
    }
}
```

Comment: Just... put this code in a loop from 1-100 and use the loop value for `check`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have almost all of the code correct, you just need to put it in the right place. For example, your println statements need to be inside the for loop and your for loop needs to start at 1 and increment by 1 to 100.

```
for(int x = 0; x < 101; x++) 
{
   if(x == 2)
      System.out.println(x + " is a prime number");
   if(x % 2 == 0)
      System.out.println(x + " is not a prime number);
   else
      System.out.println(x + " is a prime number);
}
```

I just helped a friend with almost this exact problem, so this couldn't be better timing. I don't know if your scanner is going to be used, but this works if you are just looking for prime numbers from 1-100.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, it seems your Scanner isn't being used anywhere. Maybe your code is incomplete?

You can replace the Scanner part where you get the input from the user with a for loop that will give the number to you. Like so:

```
for(int number = 1; number <= 100; number++) {
    // code for checking if number is prime or not
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at code below, let me know if something is unclear, ask, don't just read and copy:

```
package com.company;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        out:

        for (int i = 1; i <= 100 ; i++) {
            for (int j = 2; j <= i / 2 ; j++) {
                if (i % j == 0) {
                    System.out.println(i + " is not prime number.");
                    continue out;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(i + " is prime number.");
        }
    }
}
```

So to just walk over the code real quick:

1.) Create labeled block called out:

```
out:
```

2.) Create two nested for loops to check for our numbers being prime or not

3.) If statement in the second for loop will check if our number is not prime (if it's divisible by any number from 1 to itself but not those two numbers)

4.) In case our evaluation in if statement is false we continue looping until our second loop condition fails, then we move outside of the loop and print that number is prime:

```
System.out.println(i + " is prime number.");
```

5.) In case our evaluation in if statement is true we enter the if block, we print that number is not prime and we move program control back to the labeled block we created earlier

6.) We continue doing this repeatedly until outter loop check condition fails and our program is done with it's work.

Comment: Understood most of it but just wondering why you are using out: and continue out; just use a plain continue; ?

Comment: If I use continue, the program will continue with next iteration of the second loop, it would be waste, if number is divisible by let's say 3 it is not prime and there is no need to continue checking if it's divisible by 4,5,6.....n so we print that it's false and we move on to the next number, also if I used just continue it would also print that number is not prime (if it's not) and that it's prime as well.

Answer (score 0):

/* Prime numbers are numbers that are divisible by 1 and by themselves. So, if you take the modulus of a number 'N' with all the number from 1 till 'N' and increase a count each time the modulus is zero, you can use a simple if condition at the end to check whether they are prime or not. In this code, I start from checking with number 1 and go till 100*/

```
int count ;
for(int j=1;j<=100;j++)
{
count=0;
for(int i=1;i<=j;i++)
{
if(j%i==0)
count=count+1;
}
if(count>2)
System.out.println(j+"is not a prime number");
else
System.out.println(j+"is a prime number");

}
```